# accessing pseudo elements using $(this) keyword?

Tags: jquery, pseudo-element

here is my code

```
var pollPercent = function() {
    $("#poll li").each(function(){
            var percent = $(this).attr("data-percent");
            var width = (percent / 100) * 1000;
            var el = $(this);
            $("head").append("<style>" + el + ":before {width: " + width + "px;}</style>");
    });
};

pollPercent();
```

so how can I point to each li and change its "before pseudo element"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var text = $('#poll').find('li').map(function (i) {
    var width = Math.round($(this).attr('data-percent') / 100 * 1000);
    return '#poll li:nth-child(' + (i+1) + ')::before { width: ' + width +  'px; }';
}).join('');

$(document.body).append('<style>' + text + '</style>');
```

Comment: tanx for the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth-child` to get at individual `li` elements. The `each` function helpfully provides the index.

```
$(...).each(function(index, element) {
   ... "li:nth-child(" + index + "):before" ...
})
```